# Edit embedded document in mongodb using python(pymongo)

Tags: python, mongodb

I am getting following error while updating a document inside a collection in mongodb using python using pymongo. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 x = 4
 str = "ratings.${x}.rating"
 db.amitava1.update({"_id":1},{"$inc":{[str]:1 } } )
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "", line 1, in  TypeError: unhashable type:
>   'list'***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre getting that error because you're doing `{"$inc":{[str]:1 }}`. Namely, trying to assing `[str]` as the key in the in the dictionary `{[str]:1 }`.

It says that because you cannot use a list as a key for a dictionary, because a list is unhashable. You can only use hashable types (types that have a `__hash__` function defined) key values.

It looks like you have some other issues with your code though. I think you need to use

```
str = "ratings.${x}.rating".format(x=x)
```

or something in order to replace the x in your string.

Comment: Many thanks rofls. it worked. and I have other errors also which I corrected. The final codes are as follows.                                            >>> x = 0
>>> str = "ratings.{x}.rating".format(x=x)
>>> db.amitava1.update({"_id":1},{"$inc":{str:1 } } )
{u'updatedExisting': True, u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1}